# Get the width and height of a string in pixel (PHP)

Tags: php, fonts, size, pixel, truetype

Is there any good function to calculate the pixel width and height? Can imagettfbbox be used to do that? I mean which ttf file is needed for the different fonts used by different browsers?

Thx

Comment: You want to calculate how wide and high the text will be on *browser-rendered* text?

Comment: Not possible in PHP alone. You need javascript.

Comment: Yes, would be great to have a better tag-cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PHP run's on the server there is no way to do that with PHP alone. The size of the text depends on the operating system, the browser (and the browser settings like zoom) of the client. You could however use javascript to get the size of an element once its rendered.

```
height = document.getElementById("elementId").style.height; // Will return 176px for example
width = document.getElementById("elementId").style.width; // Will return 176px for example
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a function (imagefontwidth and imagefontheight), but they only return the size of one character using the built-in fonts (which are all fixed-width). You'll get the width/height of the entire string by multiplying the number returned by the number of characters.

I don't know of any way that lets you get the width or height of a string using a custom font, but I'm interested in this too.

Hope this helps.